# Use method across all Junit Test classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I need to create the method below which I need to use in all my test classes (which are in different packages). How can I make the method available for all test classes. Any efficient way? I am using Junit 5 and Mockito.

```
public  TodosObject getObject() {
    TodosObject todosObject= new TodosObject()
    // setter ommitted for brevity

    return todosObject;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an abstract base class?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-nope.I just wanted to know if junit5 provided "something special".I am new to it

Comment: you can write your own extension and do "something" before or after every test that has a special annotation, for example. We do that: we have a special annotation `@DbTest` and when it is present certain actions are done before and after each of such method. is that what you are after?

Comment: Why not writing that method in a class of its own and using that class in your unit tests?

Answer (score 2):

A common way to do that is by putting the method in a class that all your test classes extend. Example:

```
public class TodosTest {
    protected TodosObject todosObject;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        todosObject = new TodosObject();
        // setter ommitted for brevity
    }
}

public class MyTodosTest extends TodosTest {
    @Test
    void testWithTodos() {
        // access todoObject here...
    }
}
```